# How to get all values from guava LoadingCache without hitting Database everytime

Tags: java, guava

One of my methods I need is getAll() which will return all records from a table.  I want to cache these values using google cache.

The getAll() uses asMap() from the cache and this will only return values that are currently cached.

My question is how to I implement getAll() without hitting the DB everytime?  I was thinking I could hit DB and do a count, check the cache count, if they are unequal, loop through the keys the  DB returned and force a load.  Or set a boolean the first time getAll() is called.

Please advise this doesnt seem right.  My test for get all:

```
    public void cache_get_all_success() {
    when(mockDAO.getContractModel("AAA")).thenReturn(CATEGORY_A);
    when(mockDAO.getContractModel("BBB")).thenReturn(CATEGORY_B);

    ContractCategoryCache cache = new ContractCategoryCache(mockDAO);
    Optional<ContractCategoryModel> modelA = cache.get("AAA");

//test passes but I want this to be 2
    assertEquals(1,cache.getAll().size());

}
```

implementation of getAll():

```
 public List<ContractCategoryModel> getAll() {
//only returns currently cached values, I want all values from DB even if the values were never access yet
    List<ContractCategoryModel> models = contractCategoryCache.getAll();
    return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(models)
            ? new ArrayList<>()
            : models.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ContractCategoryModel::getCategory))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: *I was thinking I could hit DB and do a count...* That's still hitting the DB every time. Or do you just want to avoid a full table scan?

Comment: Can you have the code that updates the table invalidate the cache?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to warm up the cache. You can do this either by using [`Cache#putAll(Map<K, V>)`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) or using [LoadingCache#getAll(Iterable)](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#getAll(java.lang.Iterable)) and overloading `CacheLoader#loadAll(Iterable)` in your implementation.

In your case, for the first solution you'd have to create a map from a `List<ContractCategoryModel>` returned from your `getAll()` or even change its contract to return the `Map<String, ContractCategoryModel>` in the first place.

Regarding the second solution, please read `getAll()` javadocs as well as the corresponding [`loadAll()`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#loadAll(java.lang.Iterable)) one. The most important note:

> This method should be overridden when bulk retrieval is significantly more efficient than many individual lookups. Note that `LoadingCache.getAll(java.lang.Iterable<? extends K>)` will defer to individual calls to `LoadingCache.get(K)` if this method is not overridden.